# Create new opportunity if Stage is Closed Won and 90 days before Contract End Date

Tags: trigger, opportunity, businessprocess

The idea is to create a new opportunity named "Opp-name + Renewal", after the Stage is changed to Closed Won and 90 days before the Contract End Date. Different Record Type needs to be used, but some fields are just copied from the old opportunity.

At this moment, Stage is changed to Closed Won automatically when a file with the specific name is attached to the opportunity(I have a code for this and it works perfectly).
I thought I just need to create a process on the opportunity with criteria "Opp. Stage = Closed Won", and schedule it 90 days before the Contract End Date. But, this doesn't work. 
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? I believe a couple of lines can be added to the code of the trigger, but that's not the option for me because I don't know how to do it...

Here is the code written on Attachment:

```
trigger SetTitleToAttachment on Attachment (after insert) {

Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();

//go through all inserted attachments
for(Attachment att: Trigger.new){
    if(att.name == 'Countersigned Order Form' &&
        Schema.Opportunity.SObjectType == att.ParentId.getSobjectType()){
        oppIds.add(att.ParentId);
    }
}

List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
for(Id oppId : oppIds){
    oppsToUpdate.add(new Opportunity(Id = oppId, StageName = 'Closed Won'));
}

update oppsToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, I belive if you post the code sample which you have written, it will easier for the community to help you.

Comment: Ok. I will edit now. Thank you.

P.S. A friend of mine wrote the code. I don't know how to write codes.

Comment: The update of opp stage to closed won would trigger the process.  The issue is w your process.  Can you spell out your process criteria, and how you have tested it to determine its not working?

Comment: I created a process on Opportunity. Process starts Only when records is created(this may be a problem, but, if I select When a record is created or edited, then I can't set Scheduled Actions). Criteria is Opportunity Stage equals Closed Won. Time for Actions to Execute is 0 days before Renewal Date(this field is populated from a quote). The Action Type is Create a Record, and Opportunity is selected.

I activated the process and then uploaded a file to the Opportunity. Opp. Stage is changed to Closed Won, but new Opportunity isn't created.

Comment: I don't see any code which create new opportunity here.

Comment: @Reshma There is no code for that because I tried to do it with Process Builder. I realized that it can't be done with the Process and I found the code for the new opportunity and adjust it to my needs.